# Setting up a CNAME for an S3 bucket using Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I need the following url

http://liangpai.s3.amazonaws.com/uploadImage/shareImage/2012-10/506dc1ef71dcf.png

showing as:

http://imgs.liangpai.me/uploadImage/shareImage/2012-10/506dc1ef71dcf.png

My S3 bucket name is “liangpai”. On Route 53, I created a new CNAME named “imgs”, the value I entered is “liangpai.s3.amazonaws.com”

After this I don’t see the S3 web link changes to my domain link.

Anything wrong here?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

S3 CNAMEs require the bucket name to match the host name. If you want S3 to serve from `imgs.langpai.me`, you need to create a bucket named `imgs.langpai.me`. See [the S3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HostingExistingDomainOnS3.html) for more.

You could create a CloudFront distribution to answer to `imgs.langpai.me` (see [CloudFront CNAME support](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)) have it and forward requests to `langpai.s3.amazonaws.com`. This would, of course, also incur CloudFront charges.

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1 : S3 direct CNAME by bucket name**

You can create a CNAME record by bucket name following these steps.

1. Create a bucket name using the same name you will use for your dns entry.  i.e. *subdomain.mydomain.net*
2. Create a cname record for *subdomain.mydomain.net* to *s3.amazonaws.com*
3. Set permissions on your bucket based on the access you plan to grant

**Method 2 : Static Website on S3**

If you are serving static content such as images, files, etc. you can use **"Static Website Hosting"** for your **S3 bucket**.

Select your bucket by clicking the bucket icon ([image]) and select the "properties" tab on the right and expand "Static Website Hosting". In the Static Website Hosting panel, select the radio button to "Enable website hosting" and set an index and error document.  It this point, you will see an "Endpoint" name in this panel.  Simple create a DNS CNAME record with the endpoint as the value.  You can read the entire [Amazon Walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)
here.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vyke, can i point my subdomain called as "download.abc.com" to a bucket named download.abc.com? I haven't turned on static website hosting, cause it is simply used for downloading executables. Creating CName record for the same doesnt work-does this mean I ought to have configured it as static website for it to work- any ideas? Your answer on Method -1 says I need to point it s3.amazonaws.com- would it work if there are other buckets as well?

Comment: Seems that just adding a CNAME to the Endpoint of the S3 bucket (even after you enable static website) does not work. As the results is:
NoSuchBucket
It seems that willglynn is correct in stating that you need to have the same bucket name as your CNAME record

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Using your own bucket CNAME:

```
echo S3::getAuthenticatedURL("s3bucket.mydomain.com", $uri, 3600, true);
```

but you putobject file check for read for Everyone 
premisssion type:

> S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ

$s3->**putObjectFile**($tmp, $bucketname , $path.$filename, **S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ**)